# How git tag can add more meaning to artifact name?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-commit, sdlc

Currently we give artifact name as `releasenumber-sprintnumber-jenkinsbuildnumber-SNAPSHOT.jar`

But we are planning to map every commit tag to the version of artifact generated from build.

So, artifact name will be `releasenumber-gittag-SNAPSHOT.jar`

---

So, To make it more helpful at build-QA-release phase of pipelines,

what should git tag look like, when developer tags the commit?

These artifact names will be part of `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` in java build as dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use the short sha from the git commit alongside the Jenkins build number. My reason is there are two parts to producing the same artefact:

1. Building from the same version of the source code
2. Building in the same environment with the same dependencies

On occasions I have seen a patch to the operating system on a build server cause a bug when re-building the same code. Therefore, by recording both the commit id (short sha from git) and the build id (build number from Jenkins) you can identify exactly where a build came from.